# Is rms value of a positive varying DC voltage same with its mean value?

Tags: dc, rms

I know that rms of an AC is totally different than its mean. But what if the voltage is not alternating(DC) but varying by time. For example a noise with a huge offset.

How is varying DC measured by voltmeters? Mean or rms? Or as in my question are they the same thing for a varying DC?

Comment: "Varying DC" is still AC, just with a non-zero offset.

Comment: are u sure? as I know alternating means the polarity of the voltage or the direction of the current should alternate i.e. current should move back and forth in opposite directions.  a varying positive DC is not AC.

Comment: When we say "DC" we usually mean absolutely constant and not changing. Most interesting signals have both a DC component and an AC component. The "offset" is the DC component. Any variation around the offset is AC.

Comment: Alternating current means the flow direction of electrons are back and forth. If a DC is varying are some of the electrons going against the others???

Comment: It might be better for you to think of AC as anything that is not DC.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, varying DC is *not* AC.  A time varying signal doesn't necessarily *alternate* in polarity.  Indeed, the signal \$v(t) = 1 + \cos \omega t\$ is *periodic* and *time varying* but is not *alternating*.  Clearly, it has a constant component and an alternating *component* (with zero time average) but these are the components, not the signal as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rms voltage is given by

\$\sqrt{\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v^2(t) \mathrm dt}\$

The mean voltage is given by

\$\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v(t) \mathrm dt\$

As you can see, these are not the same, except in special cases. A pure positive dc voltage is one such special case.

However, if the dc component of voltage is much bigger than any ac components, the rms and mean will be very close to each other. This could apply to the case of "noise with a huge offset".

Comment: what if one connects a varying DC to a voltmeter with DC setting? Does voltmeter take the mean or rms again? What counts in general?

Comment: On the DC setting, the multimeter will give you the mean voltage over some integration interval (like my second equation). The RMS setting is more tricky. Some meters have a "true RMS" capability which gives something like my first equation; others use a simpler circuit that assumes the signal has no DC offset and will not give the actual rms value when dc offset is present (and maybe not when the signal isn't a pure sinusoid).

Comment: you mean in AC settings there is AC coupling? Im calibrating a little dc generator and I noticed when I plot the output at constant rotation speed it deviates more than I expected(varying DC with a considerable AC component). Im not sure if I should take rms or the mean value. If the person who check the little dc generator using a voltmeter then I should take the mean then since u say voltmeter measures the mean for DC voltage outputs.

Comment: AC coupling depends on the equipment you're using to measure with. A cheapo multimeter with an AC setting will no doubt AC-couple the signal, but not so well - a 'predictable' noise (e.g. 50/60Hz interferance from the mains) may be measured accuratelyn but a gaussian noise pattern may confuse it. As @ThePhoton said, a "true RMS" device is more likely to give you a closer answer. Also, noise is always specified as RMS in datasheets etc. so use that. Think about what happens if the output of your generator drops to 0V yet it's still noisy; no DC offset, so would you ever use mean? Nope, RMS!

Answer (score 2):

Varying DC *is* AC.

RMS is "Root Mean Square", which is the square root of the average of the square.  The term "average" is a clue that some time judgement is envolved.  For a repeating signal, that would usually be the repetion period.  For something else, you have to decide over what time interval you are going to average or low pass filter to get a answer, as apposed to waiting longer and getting a more "averaged" answer.

If the signal is varying so slowly that you consider it a "fixed" value that is changing a little over time, then the RMS value is the same as the instantaeous value.  In that sense, you can say the RMS value is going up and down with the voltage of the signal.  However, then the distinction between RMS and instantaneous voltage is not useful.  Usually we apply "RMS" to signals that change fast enough compared to our period of relevance.

For example, a resistor will heat up proportional to the square of the RMS voltage applied to it.  100 VDC and 100 VAC create the same heating, as long as the AC frequency is "high" compared to time scales we care about.  For heating coils in a toaster, 50 or 60 Hz is much faster than our time scale, so RMS makes sense in that context.

Comment: here are Direct current examples from wikipedia: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Current_rectification_diagram.svg What do u say?

Comment: *Varying DC is AC.* - No, actually it isn't and you *ought* to know this.  If *varying DC* is taken to mean changing with time but not *alternating* in polarity then, *by definition*, it is not AC (indeed, a *periodic* signal doesn't necessarily change polarity).  However, it *is* true that "varying DC" can be *decomposed* into a time average *constant* component and a *genuinely alternating* (AC) component with zero time average.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri thats what I knew. I have a question for you though. If a 5 Volt DC has little ripples, does that mean some electrons flow opposite direction? Or still all electron flow is same direction?

Comment: @user16307, you're mixing voltage and current together improperly.  If the "5 Volt DC with little ripples" is across a resistor then, yes, the associated current is unidirectional.  However, if that voltage is across a capacitor, the associated *current* is bidirectional.

Comment: so depending on the electronic component we have AC or DC. I think you mean when there is a decrease in voltage the current will flow opposite direction to compensate the voltage drop. smells something like lenz law.

Answer (score 2):

> How is varying DC measured by voltmeters? Mean or rms? Or as in my
>   question are they the same thing for a varying DC?

Think of a DC voltmeter as it used to be - a moving coil meter with a needle pointing to the number on the scale. A steady dc voltage meant the needle moved to a certain position and the correct voltage was indicated. If that dc voltage were superimposed with a high frequency alternating waveform that mathematically didn't alter the average dc voltage, then the meter's needle would not change position. The problem arises when the alternating part slows down and the meter's needle is seen to fluctuate around the "mean" position.

The mass of the needle isn't enough to stop the meter indicating the fluctuations.

Even RMS meters suffer from the same dilemma - what time constant do you choose to make the measurement over OR, how much mass should the needle system have? More mass means longer times to respond to a regular dc voltage being placed at its terminals. It's a compromise.

It's exactly the same problem for digital meters - what time constant do you choose when making a measurement.

Comment: Im calibrating a little dc generator and I noticed when I plot the output voltage at constant rotation speed it deviates more than I expected(varying DC with a considerable AC component). Im not sure if I should take rms or the mean value. If the person who check the little dc generator using a voltmeter then I should take the mean then since Photon says(upstairs) voltmeter measures the mean for DC voltage outputs. What would you chose?

Comment: What are you trying to calibrate - that's important. If you are interested in the generator's power delivering capabilities i.e. you are "calibrating" efficiency then RMS is the only answer when delivering power into a resistive load.

Comment: no not power they only want to see the voltage output versus rotation-speed. its a toy dc generator. when I give them the calibration equation they will use this to estimate the rotation speed. the point is I dont know how they measure the voltages(with a voltmeter or a daq). So I wanted to know how voltmeter DC voltage measures.

Comment: OK, the problem is the slow speed stuff - I understand the question now. In these circumstances you need to take the DC level but somehow apply a large filter (heavy sluggish needle) to the signal or it won't make any sense on a digital voltmeter. You can do that with a long time constant RC filter if that helps.

Comment: i use data acquisition device, open the saved data in MATLAB and plot it in time domain. Here at a constant rotation speed for 1 minute data acq. I have a varying DC voltage(DC with some weird non-periodic ripples). I can both take mean or rms of this data. The point is Im assuming if they use a voltmeter and if it measures mean value so I should take the mean value of the voltage output when calibration versus speed.

Comment: Taking the mean is best but, like you hint, what happens on the ground floor at slow speeds - "they" need to know what the pitfalls are. Talk the "they" and see what they expect.

Answer (score 0):

DC implies all positive numbers, if a portion of you signal voltage and current go below zero then you have to us RMS to figure power.  RMS current and or Voltage is how we measure power.
RMS and average or mean is the same thing when looking at voltage and current that are in one direction in other words all positive values (DC values, direct flow in one direction).  Power = I * V is simply that.
RMS is assumed that the voltage will go negative in most cases 50% of the time 120V AC (Alternating Current) so we take the square of the number and that gives us an positive value.

If at any time your signal goes below zero then you must use RMS to find, RMS power.  It all depends on what you want to measure.